# Is there any Possibility to customize a Flutter Slider?

Tags: flutter, slider

I want to Add Flutter slider in My Cricket App(App For Live Score Cricket). Is there any Possibility to customize a Flutter Slider?
if then what will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that can easily be customized in [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html). I would suggest playing around with in on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev) and try the `activeColor` and `inactiveColor`properties, and wrapping it with a [SliderTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderTheme-class.html). The `SliderTheme` allows you to define custom [SliderThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData-class.html):

> This theme is for both the Slider and the RangeSlider. The properties that are only for the Slider are: tickMarkShape, thumbShape, trackShape, and valueIndicatorShape.